# How to reorientation as axial axis of raw image from brainweb

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, computer-vision

I have a raw image with the information such as

```
image dimensions: zspace yspace xspace
    dimension name         length         step        start
    --------------         ------         ----        -----
    zspace                    181            1          -72
    yspace                    217            1         -126
    xspace                    181            1          -90
```

should be interpreted as follows:

```
the file scans the 3D image volume such that the 'X' coordinate changes fastest, and the 'Z' changes slowest.
the image sizes along the X-Y-Z axes are 181x217x181 voxels (pixels).
the voxel sizes along the X-Y-Z axes are 1x1x1 mm.
```

One (unsigned) byte is used for each voxel, and the data is scaled such that it will use the entire 0...255 range of values.

Currently, I am using below code to read that raw file. It can be read the raw image and display as right figure. However, it does not look like my expected result where image is reorientation as axial axis.

*Could you help me solving it by Matlab code?*

```
filepath=strcat('t1_icbm_normal_1mm_pn5_rf20.rawb');
fid = fopen(filepath,'r');    
rima=zeros(dim(1:3));
for z=1:dim(3),    
  rima(:,:,z) = fread(fid,dim(1:2),'uchar');  
end;
fclose(fid);
imshow(rima(:,:,91),[]); %% Show slice 91th
```

[image]

The reference link is http://brainweb.bic.mni.mcgill.ca/about_data_formats.html .
The input file can be downloaded from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4mkcoy96fk42d7a/t1_icbm_normal_1mm_pn5_rf20.rawb?dl=0) or [brainweb](http://brainweb.bic.mni.mcgill.ca/selection_normal.html)

Comment: From your images it is impossible to see if it's a row major vs column major issue (dimension 1 and 2 flipped) or maybe something else. Use the same example slice (e.g. the one on the expected result with the black circle) to make sure you get the right output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why is because when MATLAB reads in data, it places the data **in column major order**.  This means that the data you read in via rows get placed in columns.  Therefore, this has the appearance that your image gets rotated 90 degrees and reflected.

One easy solution would be to take your matrix and transpose each slice individually.  A simple call to [`permute`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) should do the trick:

```
rima = permute(rima, [2 1 3]);
```

The above code swaps the second and first dimensions over each slice of your matrix, effectively performing a transpose of each slice independently.  I've also noticed that when you do this, there is a reflection across the horizontal axis.  Make a call to [`flipdim`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flipdim.html) to fix this:

```
rima = flipdim(permute(rima, [2 1 3]), 1);
```

To reproduce, I've downloaded the file and ran the code on my computer.  I show the 91th slice before and after I `permute` and `flipdim`:

```
filepath=strcat('t1_icbm_normal_1mm_pn5_rf20.rawb');
fid = fopen(filepath,'r'); 
dim = [181 217 281]; %// Added for code to run   
rima=zeros(dim(1:3));
for z=1:dim(3),    
  rima(:,:,z) = fread(fid,dim(1:2),'uchar');  
end;
fclose(fid);
imshow(rima(:,:,91),[]); %% Show slice 91th

%// New - Permute dimensions and flip rows
rima = flipdim(permute(rima, [2 1 3]), 1);
figure;
imshow(rima(:,:,91),[]); %%// Show corrected slice
```

---

Here's what we get for before and after:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, But it is seem invert of my expected result. I will updated my image for clear vision

Comment: @user3051460 - Ah, then one call to `flipdim` will work.  I'll update my post.

Comment: @user3051460 - Try now.

Comment: @user3051460 - My pleasure. Good luck!